# Add visible cells of a range to array

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to get the values of the visible cells of a range into an array.

My code makes the array carry the values until the first non visible cell then stops.

```
Public Function ListeMaschinen() As Variant

Dim Auswahl As Range

With Sheets("qry_TechnischesDatenblatt")
Set Auswahl = .Range(.Range("A2:B2"), .Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

ListeMaschinen = Auswahl

End Function
```

If I select the range it shows all the cells I want marked.

```
Auswahl.Select
```

Comment: Hey @J.Chomel, the problem is even when I insert
`Auswahl.Select

ListeMaschinen = Selection.Value`
It only contains the Values until the first invisible cell although the right Cells are selected.

Comment: You will have to loop using this approach.

Comment: My bad, I was not relevant. This had nothing to do with `xlDow` :D

Comment: @Rory can you explain this to me please?

Comment: I mean you can't simply assign the range to the Variant - you will only ever get the first area's values. You have to loop through the visible cells and populate the array that way unless you can use a formulaic approach to limiting the data you want - then, as long as the formula is under 255 characters, you can use Evaluate to get the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I have added the range cells to an array.

```
Sub examp()
Dim rng As Range, cll As Range, i As Integer, a(100) As Variant
Set rng = Range(Range("A2:B2"), Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
i = 0
For Each cll In rng
a(i) = cll.Value
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Sumit Jain, thank you very much, this was a good hint. I justed itered through the cells like you did and pasted the Values into the array.
Its solved now. :))

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting a Variant variable equal to a Range object without using the Set statement.

The following works with the little testing I did. Of course, if you declare the function type and other variables as Range type, it also works.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim myVar As Variant

Set myVar = myList()

Debug.Print myVar.Address

End Sub

Public Function myList() As Variant
Dim myRng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myRng = .Range(.Range("A1:B1"), .Range("A1:B1").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

Debug.Print myRng.Address

Set myList = myRng

End Function
```

Comment: Hey @OldUgly, first thank you for your help.
I think I did not describe exactly enough what i want.
I want an array of the Values of the unfiltered cells like this:
123   JKL
456   ABC
789   DEF

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

When I do this:

```
Public Function ListeMaschinen() As Variant
  Dim  Auswahl As Range
  With Sheets("qry_TechnischesDatenblatt")
      Set Auswahl = .Range(.Range("A2:B2"),  .Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  End With
  MsgBox Auswahl.Address
  Set ListeMaschinen = Auswahl
  'Auswahl.Select
End Function
```

I get an `Address` composed of 2 parts: the visible parts!
[image]

### But when I remove the `SpecialCells`

```
Public Function ListeMaschinen() As Variant
  Dim Auswahl As Range
  With Sheets("qry_TechnischesDatenblatt")
      Set Auswahl = .Range(.Range("A2:B2"), .Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown))
  End With
  MsgBox Auswahl.Address
  Set ListeMaschinen = Auswahl
End Function
```

I get one single part, which Is what I get when using `Select` too.

[image]

### I tested!

```
Sub test()
  Dim myVar As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  Set myVar = ListeMaschinen()
  For Each C In myVar
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox C.Value & C.Address & "-" & i
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @J. Chomel first thank you for your help. I think I did not describe exactly enough what i want. I want an array of the Values of the unfiltered cells like this: (a, b) (sd, ds) (d, g)...(d, g) (d, g)

Comment: Then we can use the `set ListeMaschinen = Auswahl` proposed by OldUgly

Comment: Then ListeMaschinen only contains the Values until the first filtered Cell.
In this example only the Values until row 5. :-/ @J. Chomel

Comment: Did you use the second code part (without `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` ?)

Comment: When I remove the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` then I get the Values of the filtered Rows too. That's my problem. @J. Chomel

Comment: well with above sub `test()` I wrote to test, It loops over the hidden cells. What Excel release are you with?

Comment: Its solved now. My problem was that I tried to use the variant as a List for a Combobox. I had to iter through all the cells, thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comments earlier, here is a method that will work subject to some limitations:

You can't have more than 65536 rows of data; and
You can't have really long text (911 chars+), or blank visible cells; and
The data should not contain the string "|~|"

If those conditions are met, you can use something like this:

```
Dim v
Dim sFormula              As String
With Selection
    sFormula = "IF(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(" & .Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & ",row(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")-min(row(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")),1))," & .Address(0, 0) & ",""|~|"")"
End With
Debug.Print sFormula
v = Filter(Application.Transpose(Evaluate(sFormula)), "|~|", False)
```

You can adapt this to work round the third limitation by changing the alternate text in the formula string.

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) I was trying to find a way to loop through visible rows in a table without going through all the rows and checking if they are visible as this was consuming too much time on a large table. Below is the solution I was able to come up with. It is a function that returns an array of the absolute row numbers of visible rows in a given Range.

```
Function GetVisibleRows(LookupRange As Range) As Integer()
    Dim VisibleRange As Range, Index As Integer, Area As Range
    Static VisibleRows() As Integer    
    
    Set VisibleRange = LookupRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim VisibleRows(0)
    Index = 0
    
    For Each Area In VisibleRange.Areas
        If Index = 0 Then
            VisibleRows(Index) = Area.Row
            ReDim Preserve VisibleRows(Index + 1)
        End If
        
        Index = UBound(VisibleRows())
        
        If VisibleRows(Index - 1) <> Area.Row Then
            VisibleRows(Index) = Area.Row
            ReDim Preserve VisibleRows(Index + 1)
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Remove last empty item
    ReDim Preserve VisibleRows(UBound(VisibleRows()) - 1)
    GetVisibleRows = VisibleRows
End Function
```

If you would like to use this function in a lookup scenario, you need to convert the absolute row numbers returned by the function to relative row numbers of the table. Following worked for me.

```
RowIndex = ReturnedRowIndex - LookupRange.Rows(1).Row + 1
```

Good luck!